# infinispan key replication across servers

Tags: key, infinispan

I would like to know if there is any such config in infinispan where in a key can be replicated across different servers in a clustered environment. For example, I have a key, say key 1. In my cluster I would like to run node 1 & node 2 on server 1 and node 3 & node 4 on server 2. My requirement is, can key 1 be distributed among server 1 and server 2 on any of their nodes, provided all the 4 nodes are up and running. I tried the below infinispan config on my local servers and key is being replicated on a different node in the same server but not on a different server. Kindly help.

```
<global >
        <globalJmxStatistics enabled="true" />
        <transport clusterName="demoCluster">
            <properties>
                <property name="configurationFile" value="jgroups.xml"/>
            </properties>
        </transport>
    </global>
    <default>
        <jmxStatistics enabled="true" />    
        <clustering mode="distribution">
          <sync>
            <!-- <hash numOwners="2"/> -->
          </sync>
        </clustering>
   </default>
```

Comment: The reason why it works in the same server and not across servers is a probably a network issue, or a JGroups configuration issue. You should pass `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` and `-Djgroups.bind_addr=x.x.x.x` where `x.x.x.x` is the address in each server that connects to the other server via the LAN/WAN that you have set up. Also, check whether TCP or UDP used in jgroups.xml...etc.

Comment: Hi Galder, I have answered the question :). That config worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an attribute called machineId in transport element of the infinispan cache config. Please refer to https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/ServerHinting for more details. Hope this would help someone :)